# What is the purpose of SSL/TLS renegotiation?

Tags: ssl

What is the purpose of SSL/TLS renegotiation and under exactly what circumstances does a renegotiation occur?

Please note I am not asking about the vulnerabilities associated with a renegotiation, there are many sources that are talking about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It occurs after either side has expired the session and continues sending data. It means either that the session has simply expired due to timeout, or that a peer wants to change the cipher suite, or wants to request a peer certificate and hasn't already done so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How do you define a session? https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#appendix-F.1.4 refers to the term session but does not define what it is. Does a session start when the master_secret is negotiated by client and server? The aforementioned link says "An upper limit of 24 hours is suggested for session ID lifetimes", how is this timeout value set? Is it set using TLS record field? If so, what is the actual header name? (I looked through TLS records fields but was unable to find it).

Comment: Found my answers.
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4366#section-2.1
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5077#section-5.6

Comment: Neither of those links is relevant. An SSL ticket is not the same thing as an SSL session, and you don't need an extended `ClientHello` to renegotiate. An SSL session is merely a collection of protocols, cipher suites, and a master secret, and it is generally (a) shared among multiple SSL connections between the same peer, and (b) expired by one or both peers under control of the SSL software layer, for example [javax.net.ssl.SSLSessionContenxt.setSessionTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSessionContext.html#setSessionTimeout-int-).

Comment: Note that renegotiation is entirely removed in TLSv1.3, so all of these use-cases are now for legacy versions only

Comment: @Siler so does that mean `SSL_read` or `SSL_write` would not return `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` in TLS v1.3?

Comment: @VijayChavda No it doesn't mean that. Those status codes are there to help you drive the OpenSSL protocol engine in non-blocking mode. They have nothing to do with TLS versions whatsoever.